# Excel - combining rows of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge

I need help with merging multipul rows in excel, I need rows by the same name and date to merge together into one line joining the tasks done into one row (date).

currently I am manually merging around 1000 rows of data.

please see example below.

[image: what i need it to look like]

Comment: Any possiblity of collisions? i.e. two numbers needing to go into the same cell….

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Power Query:

Select the Range- go to `Data`- `Get & Transform Data`- `From Sheet`- open `Power Query Editor`- select `Columns Task 1- Task 6`- go to `Transform`- select `Unpivot Columns`- Select `Attribute` column- under `Transform` Tab select `Pivot Column`- `Value Column` select `Value`- `Advanced option` select `Sum`- change the Date format and `close and load to...`

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is with sumifs. In essence, for each task, sum every data cell for which the names and dates match those of the summary line.

First, clear out the range C16:H20 but retain the names and dates in range A16:B20.

Then, in cell C16, put the following formula:

`=SUMIFS(C$2:C$12,$A$2:$A$12,$A16,$B$2:$B$12,$B16)`

Fill down to C20, select range C16:C20 and drag right to fill to H16:H20. The '$' shouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If using Excel 365, you can do the following:

- Delete the contents of A16 to B20, then enter the following formula in A16:

```
=UNIQUE(A3:B12)
```

- Format B16 to B20 to display the date in the appropriate format.
- Enter the following formula in C16:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(C$3:C$12,MATCH(1,($A16=$A$3:$A$12)*($B16=$B$3:$B$12)*(C$3:C$12<>""),0)),"")
```

- Drag it to fill the other cells

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

You can also obtain your desired results using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**
*Note that we do some extra steps so as to retain the original data order in the results, since Pivoting will not necessarily do that*

```
let
    //change table name in next line to the actual name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],

    //get list of task names and "Names" so as to retain the original order
    taskNames= List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),2),
    names = List.Distinct(Source[Name]),

    //set proper data types for Name and Date columns
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Name", type text}, {"Date", type date}
        }),

    //make a column arrangement of the tasks, which will remove the blanks   
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Name", "Date"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

    //Then pivot back to list in original order without unnecessary blanks.
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", taskNames,
                             "Attribute", "Value", List.Sum),

    //sort names to original order
    sorted = Table.Sort(#"Pivoted Column",each List.PositionOf(names, [Name]))
in
    sorted
```

[image]